# Convert a list to string without commas

Tags: python

I have a list with the format
`[[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [0,0]]`
Now I want to convert it into the format `"((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))"`

I have tried some solutions, but it is not working i.e

```py
def conv(l):
    return str(map(lambda a: " ".join(a), l))
```

My sublist will always have 2 points i.e x,y and main list can have many points i.e [[x,y],[x,y],......]

Comment: What's the logic behind the `((` `))`…?

Comment: What's the purpose of converting your list to that format? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I have a function which accepts the strings in the following format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
','.join(f'{x} {y}' for (x,y) in l)
```

You have two processes you need to combine. First you need to unpack each pair of co-ordinates into a string like `0 1` for `[0, 1]` this could be done using a join but, IMO, it's easier and clearer to simply used a formatted string, that's the `f'{x} {y}'` which replaces the `{x}` and `{y}` with the value of the variable `x` and `y`.

Second, you need to read these pairs out of the containing list `l`, this can be done using a comprehension. In your case you want to unpack as you go which you can do with `for (x, y) in l`. You can then combine these with a `join` to introduce the commas between co-ordinates that you want.

So, including your encasing parentheses we end up with a function definition of:

```
def conv(l):
    return f"(({','.join(f'{x} {y}' for (x,y) in l)}))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the inner lists with a space and the outer list with a comma:

```py
l = [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [0,0]]
s = ','.join(' '.join(map(str, sub)) for sub in l)
print(f"(({s}))")
```

Will give:

```
((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using a list comprehension:

```py
inp = [[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [0,0]]
output = '((' + ','.join([str(x[0]) + ' ' + str(x[1]) for x in inp]) + '))'
print(output)  # ((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it very simple like this:

```
"((" + ",".join(f"{x[0]} {x[1]}" for x in l) + "))"
```

Output:  '((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'